# facebook error (#200) Permissions

Tags: php, facebook, web, access-token

***edit:***

I do some check`s more, that do like just for who in the account friend-list.

lets say A friend B but not friend C, and B friend C
A can do like to B post, but not to C, but B can do like C and to A

Why that happen!?

Original:

I try to like post/photo with users, they give my access and i use the token
That what i tried:

```
$access = $row['access_token'];
$like = $facebook->api($post_id . "/likes", 'POST',  array (
        'access_token' => $access));
```

And that a access i got:

```
email,user_birthday,publish_actions, read_stream
```

and that error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: (#200) Permissions error thrown in........(the dir)
```

Thanks to helpers :)

Comment: what would you need read_stream for this? that permission will not get approved anyway, unless you are building an app for platforms like TVs.

Comment: @luschn Other permissions for other things :P why that error? the post is "public" and account give me access and i use his access...

Comment: what access token is this? is an access token created by an admin of the app?

Comment: btw, not sure what you want to do in general. user access tokens are only valid for up to 2 hours, or 60 days if you extend it. after that, the user has to go back to the app and refresh the token.

Comment: anyway, i am 99% sure i got the answer correct, should have taken a closer look at your api call :)

Comment: The token for 60 days and i check that on my users... i can do like to friends posts, but if i try to non-friedn, i god that error. why :P

Comment: ok, my bad, i was thinking wrong with my answer. anyway, why would you want to post likes as someone else? sounds like you want to do some kind of "autoliking"?

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that those permissions need to get approved by Facebook before using them as user. Before approval, they will only work for App admins and every other user will only be able to use basic permissions. See changelog and review guidelines:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review

Meaning, non-admins will get an Access Token, but before getting approval for the permissions, those Access Tokens will not be able to use the `publish_actions` permission - and that´s what you need for liking via API.

Comment: I didn`t try to like page. just post (status) or photo... and i use that: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/object/likes#publish

Comment: oh, my bad, i was thinking about something else, sorry.

Comment: yea i know it, i check the perms on my test accounts and when i try to like my posts with other accounts that work, but other frien (and that not in friends list) that didn`t work

Comment: what test accounts? are those real user profiles or just app test accounts?

Comment: real. I add them to "testers"

Comment: just fyi, it is not allowed to own more than 1 account on facebook, you know...that is what test users are for ;)

Comment: anyway, if they got a role in the app, the permissions should work. do you get a more detailed error message? would be interesting to know the whole message.